# Problematic Audio Visualizer in Firefox (34.0.5) || Issues with Firefox and Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio

I have trying to rack my brain around this, and I have no idea what the issue is.

I have an audio player, with custom controls, and the javascript to activate these controls works just fine, until I add in the visualizer Web Audio API.

HTML:

```
<div id="audioContainer">
   <audio id="audio" controls preload="metadata">
      <source src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/halleonard-audio/guitarinstructor-clips/686095-1-Clip-Play.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
      <!-- Flash fallback -->
      <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flash-player.swf?videoUrl=http://s3.amazonaws.com/halleonard-audio/guitarinstructor-clips/686095-1-Clip-Play.mp3" width="960" height="540">
         <param name="movie" value="flash-player.swf?videoUrl=http://s3.amazonaws.com/halleonard-audio/guitarinstructor-clips/686095-1-Clip-Play.mp3" />
         <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
         <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
         <param name="flashvars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image=img/poster.jpg&amp;file=flash-player.swf?videoUrl=http://s3.amazonaws.com/halleonard-audio/guitarinstructor-clips/686095-1-Clip-Play.mp3" />
      </object>
      <!-- Offer download -->
   </audio>
    <ul id="media-controls" class="controls">
        <li><button id="playpause" type="button">Play/Pause</button></li>
        <li><button id="rewind10" type="button">Rewind 10</button></li>
        <li><button id="loop" type="button">Loop</button></li>
        <li class="progress">
          <progress id="progress" value="0" min="0">
             <span id="progress-bar"></span>
          </progress>
        </li>
        <li><button id="mute" type="button">Mute/Unmute</button></li>
        <li><button id="volinc" type="button">Vol+</button></li>
        <li><button id="voldec" type="button">Vol-</button></li>
        <li><button id="fs" type="button">Fullscreen</button></li>
    </ul>
    <canvas id="visualizer">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var supportsAudio = !!document.createElement('audio').canPlayType;

if (supportsAudio) {
    var audioContainer = document.getElementById('audioContainer');
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    var mediaControls = document.getElementById('media-controls');
    var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
    var progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('visualizer');

    // COMMENT OUT THE FOLLOWING
    /*
    var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
    var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
    var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
    var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    var bCtx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    frameLooper();
    */

    // COMMENT OUT THE PRECEDING

    audio.controls = false;
    mediaControls.style.display = 'block';


    playpause.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       if (audio.paused || audio.ended) audio.play();
       else audio.pause();
    });

    rewind10.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        audio.currentTime = audio.currentTime - 10;
    });

    loop.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        if (audio.loop ==  false){
            audio.loop = true;
        } else{
            audio.loop = false;
        }
    });

    mute.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        audio.muted = !audio.muted;
    });

    volinc.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       alterVolume('+');
    });
    voldec.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       alterVolume('-');
    });

    var alterVolume = function(dir) {
        var currentVolume = Math.floor(video.volume * 10) / 10;
        if (dir === '+') {
            if (currentVolume < 1) audio.volume += 0.1;
        }
        else if (dir === '-') {
            if (currentVolume > 0) audio.volume -= 0.1;
        }
    }

    audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
       if (!progress.getAttribute('max')) progress.setAttribute('max', audio.duration);
       progress.value = audio.currentTime;
       progressBar.style.width = Math.floor((audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100) + '%';
    });

    audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
       progress.setAttribute('max', audio.duration);
    });

    progress.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       var pos = (e.pageX  - this.offsetLeft) / this.offsetWidth;
       audio.currentTime = pos * audio.duration;
    });


    /* The following function runs the visualizer

    function frameLooper(){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);

        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

        bCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        var grd = bCtx.createLinearGradient(0, canvas.height, 0, 0);
         grd.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(31, 244, 31, 0.6)');  
         grd.addColorStop(.75, 'rgba(233, 21, 31, 0.8)');
         bCtx.fillStyle = grd;

        bars = 30;
        for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
            bar_x = i * 10;
            bar_width = 9;
            bar_height = -(dataArray[i] / 2);
            bCtx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
        }
    }
    */
}
```

It works fine in Chrome, but when I bring it into Firefox, the controls no longer work, the visualizer doesn't display, but I'm not getting ***ANY*** errors in the developer tools console.

Answer (score -1):

Just change  `audio.controls = true;`
See http://jsfiddle.net/bhaxt194/

Comment: Where's the Audio Visualizer in your jFiddle?  The title of this issue is *Problematic Audio Visualizer*, I just commented out the visualizer code so you could see the player work, then you uncomment it to see how it no longer works.  Did you try this in Firefox? How does simply turning the controls back on solve my issue?

Comment: to further my point, I have removed all comments for this jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/murphy1976/15sg7wjd/  Please view in Chrome AND Firefox.

Comment: I searched a lot on my side too - I puts me in the morning http://jsfiddle.net/bhaxt194/

Comment: What were your changes from the previous link you posted? This looks like the exact same thing.

Comment: You seem to be only looking at one aspect of this issue. You have only turned the controls visibility back on. Did you test in Firefox before you posted? The title of this issue says: Problematic Audio Visualizer in **Firefox** (34.0.5) || Issues with **Firefox** and Web Audio API